# How do i make my app follow along with the ios8 style

Tags: swift, ios8, styles

How can i make sure my app looks and feels like iOS 8 should? Is there a .systemFont or .systemStyle I can use to stay on track with iOS 8 or what? Can we use whatever font we like or is there a recommended font for ios 8? Is there a template I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 and 8 use Helvetica Neue for all (which is the systemFont), with its variants, Thin, Light and Ultralight.

You can follow the apple guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/

Comment: You can mark it as an answer if it's been useful for you :)